# return form statement inside a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I see the following code and it has a statement return $p. What is the significance of the return $p statement here?I want to know why would somebody return a form statement.

```
ssoWelcome: (function () {
    var $p = $('<form class="full controls"><p>Welcome <span class="username"></span>!</p><input type="submit" value="Continue" name="welcome" class="welcomeBtn"></form>');
    $p.submit(function (e) {
        C.options.postAction('redirect');
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    });
    return $p;
}())
```

Comment: This will explain EVERYTHING you need to know about JS functions ...  Including what a `return` does .. --> http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html   --  bookmark it!

Comment: As a side note, in your profile the function written has a return in it.   Even in humor, one would assume you knew how returns work  ...  Funny how deceiving perceptions on the internet can be huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't return the form statement.  It returns a jQuery object that, in turn, contains the DOM object generated by the function, which in turn is what gets assigned as the value of the `ssoWelcome` key in some object.

In short, whoever wrote this code wanted to do many things at once: create a DOM object of a Form, create a jQuery wrapper for it, assign an action on `submit`, and finally store a handle to the jQuery-wrapped form DOM object for future reference.  There are any number of reasons to store a reference to a generated object, such as wanting to add the object to the current DOM, disable it under certain circumstances, perhaps even remove it entirely.